# How does Dusk Oracle's Foreseen Hit interact with a multi-target power?

Tags: dnd-4e

This [character](http://iplay4e.appspot.com/characters/agdpcGxheTRlchQLEgtDaGFyYWN0ZXJWMhjY3fgEDA) uses Foreseen Hit with Hand of Radiance which can target 4 creatures.

[Foreseen hit](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=14043):

> Encounter        Cold, Necrotic, Shadow
>
> No Action      Personal
>
> Trigger: You make a basic attack or use an at-will attack power against an enemy.
> Effect: The triggering attack targets the lowest of the enemy’s Fortitude, Reflex, or Will. On a hit, the attack deals extra necrotic and cold damage equal to 3 + your Wisdom or Charisma modifier, and the target is slowed until the end of your next turn.

If I'm hitting 4 monsters, and I use Foreseen hit after the attack, does the power's attack line become modified for all four creatures?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**. Quoted with emphasis:

> You make a basic attack or use an at-will attack power against ***an*** enemy. Effect: The triggering attack targets the lowest of ***the enemy's*** Fortitude, Reflex, or Will.

***An*** implies a single enemy. And the effect only works on that enemy.

If you used this against each target it would be like using the encounter power 4 times.

Comment: While not exactly the same issue, I'll refer you to [your answer](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5052/does-reverent-mettle-affect-the-entire-area-of-effect/5055#5055) to one of my older questions. It seems similar in nature.

Comment: To me the keys here are: it triggers off of **an** enemy being attacked, and targets a defense of **that** enemy. I see two ways to interpret that - that enemy is effected by Forseen Hit and no others as @dpatchery indicates, or all enemies are targeted at that enemy's defense, and that seems insane.

Comment: Simon, dpatch, I basically agree with you. But it's a question worth asking.

Answer (score 4):

The snarky answer is: "whatever way your DM wants to interpret it".

The short answer is that **yes**, the way I read it, you should get Forseen Hit's bonus against all four creatures. (But again, I see a case for the other interpretation also)

The trigger for this power is not "you make an attack roll against an enemy", but "you use an attack power".

There is no reason to infer a target line other than that of the At-Will or Basic Attack power Forseen Hit is piggybacking off of. While it's clear that the choice of wording is unideal (hence the varying interpretations observed even within these two conflicting answers), I don't think the intent was to unintentionally exclude multi-target powers in the first place.

For point of comparison, consider the Wizard's "Orb of Deception" power. The trigger is "an enemy", and has verbage to support the scenario where the power has more than one target. Specifically, this clause:

> "Choose **another** enemy within 3 squares of the target. **The chosen
>   enemy cannot also be a target of the original attack.**"

The second clause only is at issue when the power has multiple targets to begin with, and the trigger: "miss an enemy" doesn't care how many targets the power had in the first place.

Likewise, for Foreseen Hit, the trigger is conclusive:

> "when you use an at-will power"

Foreseen Hit doesn't care if you're using Thunderwave or Magic Missile, just that you're using an at-will attack. "an enemy" is irrelevant, because the effect modifies:

> "the triggering attack"

and *not* "the triggering attack roll" (which **would** imply a maximal target of one).

In any case, "the enemy's" is ambiguous in regards to plurality, so that also cannot be used to determine target.

In short, this is what I consider the series of events that happen when you use this power to be:

1. You make an attack targeting *at least* one enemy.
2. You trigger "Foreseen Hit".
3. "Foreseen Hit" modifies your attack **power**.
4. You make attack rolls against every target, as normal.
5. You resolve the hit by comparing the result against each target's lowest defense, as per Foreseen Hit.
6. If a target is hit, apply Foreseen Hit's bonus damage and condition.

Comment: Definitely clarified things, so I'm glad I didn't -1.  However, I still disagree.  If multiple targets were allowed , I would expect the following verbiage: ***  You make a basic attack or use an at-will attack power. Effect: The triggering attack targets the lowest of the target's Fortitude, Reflex, or Will. On a hit, the attack deals extra necrotic and cold damage equal to 3 + your Wisdom or Charisma modifier, and the target is slowed until the end of your next turn. **** This would clearly allow multiple targets, and has no other side affects.

Comment: It could also read 'against one or more enemies' if that was it's intention. And I'm missing some side affect of an at-will attack against a non-enemy.

Comment: @GMNoob - it's just is there to mean you can't use this power to damage your allies, and need a valid target. Many attack powers use that terminology, so it's nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: I don't think that is correct, but if it is, my second comment stands :) "an enemy" and "a single enemy" mean the same thing. But 'an enemy' and 'one or more enemies' do not mean the same thing.

Comment: In other news, welcome to the site, mate! :)